# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS- How to set the default-jre with a specific version?

Tags: 18.04

I would like to install on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS an application that requires java 8.
When I want to install this application, an error is raised about the default-jre:

```
Package default-jre is not configured yet
```

However, when I tried `java - version`, the java version returned is `openjdk version 1.8.0_191`

Please note, I don't want the version 10 or 11 of java.

So, do you know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the following command to install OpenJDK 8:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```

And check the version with:

```
java -version
```

Comment: I will try this.  Do you know where I can find all these packages (manual download)? Indeed,my Ubuntu computer doesn't have any internet access.

Comment: As they stated here (https://openjdk.java.net/install/) it is only possible for some packages on this website: https://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/8 Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I have found all the packages that I need on this website: (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+package/default-jre).  Now, my application can be installed without any issue.